# Do the Vedas mention that the Vedas are divine in origin?

Tags: vedas, gods

Do the Vedas say that they are divine in origin. Or a revelation from God himself.

Comment: @Rickross what is the meaning of apaurusheya?

Comment: Divine origin (not created by man).